# How can I turn on google maps speedometer alerts on exceeding the speed limits?

Tags: google-maps-navigation

How can I turn on google maps speedometer alerts on exceeding the speed limits?

waze has a good system , it shows your speed and puts a red circle around it if you go over the speed limit.

But I don't see it on google maps

I am in the Uk and have read that google maps has rolled out that feature for the UK..
https://www.slashgear.com/google-maps-on-screen-speedometer-will-warn-you-if-youre-speeding-06579422/
"Aside from not being available on Android Auto yet, this new Google Maps feature is rolling out to users in limited markets rather slowly. Those include Argentina, Australia, Belgium, Brazil, Canada, Czech Republic, Germany, India, the Netherlands, Poland, Portugal, Sweden, the UK, and the US. No need to update anything as it seems to be a server-side switch that only Google can flip.
The on-screen speedometer is just the most recent Waze feature added to Google Maps"

I see the speedometer, just not the alert when over the speed limit.

I see pictures on google images like

[image]

But not on my phone

I have gone to settings..navigation setings..driver options.. and I have speedometer turned on and 'driving notifications' turned on, they were on anyway by default. But still it doesn't show me speed limit.

As a workaround I wouldn't mine an app that shows the speed limit in the corner of the screen but I don't know of such a thing either. The closest I have is Waze which has the speedometer with alerts, and I can make google maps small and sit it in the middle of a waze window. But then google maps is very small. I don't like waze that much i'd rather not have to use it just for that.

Comment: I would love an answser which actually gives the solution in google maps, not some other app. OP is in the UK and I would love answers also covering The Netherlands and Germany as mentioned in the question as upcoming rollouts.

Comment: @MartinZaske the accepted answer is Google maps and would work in whatever country. The apps were written in the USA

Comment: @MartinZaske the solution is giving an overlay over google maps. So if google maps is misbehaving and not showing speed, then those overlay programs are.

Comment: So basically Google Maps still does not provide this feature. So imagine I buy a nice Mercedes from a genuine dealership and have some expert apply leopard fur and bunny ears. Then people will stop me in the streets and ask "What is that? Where can I get one too?". Then I answer "It is Mercedes." And they rise an eyebrow and wait. And then I go "All right, it is a Mercedes! With an overlay. But no side effects. My Mercedes garage just loves it when I show up for regular maintenance..." Thanks guys for clarifying. Seems Google just wants to stay clear from the legal pitfalls in this context.

Comment: @MartinZaske  This doesn't look like leopard fur and bunny ears. It looks like something that anybody looking might think is part of google maps. And there's actually a lot of flexibility to the concept. It's good that android allows for that.  And it means people aren't too at the mercy of google. It'd be better if google maps were open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these apps appear to meet the requirements (not tested by me). I have requested OP to add/edit based on their tests.

- You can try [Velociraptor - Speed Limits & Speedometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pluscubed.velociraptor), which is free and links to Open Street Maps (OSM) as also appears as an overlay  on Google Maps (select auto Launch in advanced settings). It is free & [Open Source](https://github.com/pluscubed/velociraptor/issues)

> Features:
>
> • Automatically displays in any apps you choose (e.g. Google Maps)
>
> • Intelligent caching & fast refresh of speed limits
>
> • Sound alert when speed limit is exceeded
>
> • Speed limit tolerance: % and integer amounts
>
> • Transparency, size, and tap to hide setting

- Alternatively, app [Maps speed limits](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amphebia.mapsspeedlimits) . It's a paid app with one week free trial

> Maps Speed Limits shows the current speed limit in Google Maps or any other app.
>
> Speed limit alert: play a sound when speeding

**Barlop / OP adds**

Looking at the screenshot below, you see on the left of the screenshot. (red circle aside), Velociraptor showing speed limit and speed.

Also on the left, you see the red circle, that's map speed limits. (not so necessary as Velociraptor shows both speed and speed limit anyway).

The speed mentioned on the very bottom is google maps saying that, google maps suddenly decided to state the speed!

I don't mind having both, sometimes the speed limits reported can differ, as the speed limits use a different database and they can update at different positions on the road. Velociraptor makes clear it uses OSM, and i'm not sure what database map speed limits uses.

They work internationally and have an option to switch between kph and mph.

Velocirapter also has quite comprehensive settings too and is pretty easy to navigate. And the google play app velociraptor page shows some screenshots of the settings it has too.

It is an overlay so google maps is open there, and any app showing the speed or speed limit is showing it as a floating  overlay over it.

[image]

Here is another pic from [here](http://here) incase anybody doesn't believe that the above is google maps (it is). As is the pic below. And since its google maps it applies to works for whatever country you are in.

[image]

Comment: The question asked about google maps, it seems this answer is proposing a totally different app - or is this velocirapter some kind of plug-in to google maps?

Comment: @MartinZaske It's a workaround. Please see last paragraph of question

Comment: @beeshyams no it is google maps!

Comment: @MartinZaske it is an overlay, but it's very quick to try so if you tried it you'd se for yourself. And this answer stated about it being an overlay

Comment: #barlop Of course it is. My bad in not being clear. What I was referring to as "workaround" was in the context of an alternative means super imposed on Google maps, in the non availability of native means

Comment: @beeshyams you say " It(Velociraptor) is free & Open Source"  <-- Free yes, but where did you get 'open source' from?   And don't say me 'cos I don't think I wrote that (and perhaps at your suggestion, my comments were deleted so I can't prove I didn't, but I didn't!).   OSM stands for open street maps, and OSM happens to be open source.(though OSM being open source isn't that relevant to the question),

Comment: @barlop it's on the [Github](https://github.com/pluscubed/velociraptor/issues). For a moment, I was foxed too, wondering why I said that :-)